# Alter drupal 8 views in for each row

Tags: views, 8

I have a view and I want to alter the output in each row.
So I have tried [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.2.x), and [hook_preprocess_views_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7.x-3.x), but with no luck. In both of the above hooks I got data in `$view->result`, but there seems to be no way to change the rendered output.

Comment: no those are not removed instead in hook_views_pre_render($view) its not referenced, but hook_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) its referenced. so the changes can take place in later like :
$view = &$variables['view'];
$view->element['#title']['#markup'] = 'abc';

Answer (score 3):

After a long a research and development, I came to an conclusion that this could be the answer:

```
foreach ($view->result as $result) {
  $result->_entity->set('field_name', array(0 => 'value'));
}
```